# Is this Termite or Carpenter Ant Damage?

Tags: termite, insect, ants

I'm renovating a bathroom in my home in Maryland. I found this insect activity when I removed the drywall. Was it made by termites or carpenter ants, or hopefully, some benign insect? It doesn't look like there is damage to the wood, although I don't know what is happening between/inside the studs.[image]
[image]

Comment: From the photo it is hard to tell carpenter ants leave trails similar to what I think I see termites bore holes. I mother than the dark area and trails I don't see the damage normally found by these buggers. Do you have any photos of the colony?

Comment: See related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/68596/are-these-mud-tunnels-from-termites-or-carpenter-ants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell-tale of carpenter ants would be sawdust on floor or surroundings of the tunnels. Carpenter ants do not eat wood; hence, when they bore tunnels through wood, they push out the bits of wood through the holes in the wood which then accumulate in piles.

In the photographs appear to be the typical termite mud tunnels. Termites consume wood and then cover their tunnels with saliva, mud, and fecal matter. The dirt trails you see are called “mud tunnels.”

Comment: Hammer Thank you for your message. Is there a way to tell if the infestation is current or from the past? I believe the previous owner of the home had some kind of treatment done.

Comment: Knock down the tunnel and if it reappears, it is active.

Comment: I had an exterminator out and he confirmed that it's termites.